# Finding fractional derivative for functions and integrate over the differential operator

Tags: python, differentiation

I am currently writting a paper for university and struggle to calculate fractional derivatives for that paper numerically. I already got few results which don't make sense such as the 10 derivative of e^x is in the 10^6 range. That's strange. So I try to write code such that I can investigate the operator

\begin{align}
\mathcal{T}*{\mathbf{D}}{f(z)}:= \int*{\mathbf{D}} \frac{D^{\alpha}_{z_0}f(a)}{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}(z-a)^{\alpha}d\alpha
\end{align}

for real values. I want to use the RL-differential Operator for that.

So I tried to use the different python package but I got weird results and also the Rl operator does not work for any fractional derivative greater than 1 because of a zero division error. So I tried to use the df.RL function for the fractional derivative between 0 and 1 and then wanted to use other methods to differentiate the array which the df.RL gives you for the area you integrate over. But then I got the error (using the scipy.misc derivative function)

> Value after * must be an iterable, not int.

So I am still stuck at the point to define a functioning differential
operator.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.